# Method to quantify differences between prediction and outcome for factual and simulated sample

Tags: r, simulation, error, model-comparison, accuracy

I have vector with probability values `a` and binary outcome `b`:

```
a <- c(0.23,0.45,0.6,0.1,0.95,0.34,0.67) 
b <- c(0,1,1,1,0,1,0)
```

Now, I want to see how likely `b` is in fact represented by probability values in `a`.

To do this, I am simulating `r=1000` `b` based on the probability values in `a`.
Simulating first random numbers drawing from the uniform distribution (0-1) and then assigning either 1 or 0 depending whether value is below or above the probability value in `b`.

I am then summing up the differences between the outcome (0/1) and the probability value for this position by row. 
Finally, I plot the sum of differences for the simulated sample and the sum of differences for `b`and I see where in the probability distribution I have my `b`.

In my problem I also have a variance `v` associated with probability values.

I want to ask, if anyone knows any other clever sensitive way to compare the simulated sample with the statistics, as I find this is not always sensitive in my larger problem.

```
r <- 1000


v <- c(0.07,0.05,0.12,0.25,0.03,0.11,0.15)

# Simulate random numbers from uniform distribution
RandomSample <- t(replicate(r,runif(length(b), min=0,max=1)))

# Assign 0/1
UDRandomSample <- RandomSample < matrix(a[col(RandomSample)], 
                       ncol=length(a))

# Calculate differences between the outcome and prob value
Differences <- abs(UDRandomSample - matrix(a[col(RandomSample)], 
                                               ncol=length(a)))

# Sum up the differences
DifferencesSum <- rowSums(Differences)

# Calculate p value
pvalue <- sum(abs(a - b))
pvalue

# Plot results
par(mfrow=c(1,1))
hist(DifferencesSum,main=c("Sum of abs differences"))
abline(v=pvalue,col="red")
```

[image]